# Run testNG on a maven test dependency

Tags: maven, testng

I have a maven project that has a dependency on a test project. I would like to run testNG on this project:

```
<groupId>com.myGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>assembly</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
            <test>MyTest</test>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>test-suites/all-test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But nothing happens when I run **mvn clean install** on the above project. Is it possible to setup the maven-surefire-plugin to run testNG on eg. a binary dependency?

EDIT:

THis:

http://softwaremavens.blogspot.dk/2009/09/running-tests-from-maven-test-jar-in.html

seems to be spot on. Could be nice if it was possible to run the code directly from the dependency instead of having to unpack it.

Answer (score 0):

At glance i dont see any defect in your pom.xml.

Please refer [1](http://dharshanaw.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-execute-testng-tests-in-side.html) i think thats what you are looking for generating and executing test binary.

[1](http://dharshanaw.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-execute-testng-tests-in-side.html). http://dharshanaw.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-execute-testng-tests-in-side.html

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with Maven Surefire v2.15. Simply add the following kind of configuration to the surefire plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
      <dependenciesToScan>
        <dependency>com.group.id:my-artifact</dependency>
        <dependency>com.group.id:my-other-artifact</dependency>
      </dependenciesToScan>
      ...
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
  ...
</build>
```

You should also declare the actual dependencies in the dependencies section:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-other-artifact</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```